# How do you handle entity parent-child relationship in Ashley ECS?

Tags: libgdx, entity-system, entity-component

In the below code example, is a parent-child relationship of an entities. Now every child should follow its parent position, and the child could be re-positioned anywhere.

```
Entity character; // character is a parent
Entity weapon; // weapon is a child of character

Entity gun; // gun is a parent
Entity bullet; // bullet is a parent
Entity bulletShadow; // shadow is a child of bullet
```

My own solution is to have an `OwnershipComponent` which has a `Entity owner` attribute, but there's a doubt in my mind that the components should only have a data. An `Entity` is a collection of data, if I  pass this data to components this could lead to over-killing of iteration. So I've changed my mind to use its attribute `int flags`, this could now be use as an id to reference to child-parent relationship.

```
public class OwnershipComponent implements {
    public int ownerId;
}

// Entity Manager class

public void create() {
    Entity character = createCharacter();
    createWeapon(0, 0, character.flags);
}

public void createWeapon(float x, float y, int ownerId) {
    Entity weapon = engine.createEntity();
    weapon.flags = // generated unique ID from the weapon category

    OwnershipComponent ownership = engine.createComponent(OwnershipComponent);
    ownership.ownerId = ownerId;

    weapon.add(ownership);
}

public Entity getEntityById(int id) {
    return ...
}
```

I could access now the parent entity by id and transform its child position relatively.

```
// Ownership System

public void processEntity(Entity entity, float deltaTime) {
    OwnershipComponent ownership = Mapper.ownership.get(entity);
    Entity parent = EntityManager.getEntityById(ownership.ownerId);
}
```